# Can I account for a shift in a timeseries from quarter x onwards in the seas() package

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I want to seasonally adjust the following time series:

```
s <- c(37.74991 , 37.77515 , 37.75384 , 37.94780 , 39.77417, 39.79430 , 39.81612,
       39.99021,  42.20018,  42.22210,  42.26033,  42.45065,  45.07874,  45.15395,
       45.22697,  45.51945,  47.79920,  47.85800,  47.92614,  48.25480,  49.91503,
       49.91005,  50.04165,  50.42833,  51.72783,  51.60934,  51.61586,  51.89149,
       55.29518,  55.17836,  55.22256,  55.55186,  57.44819,  57.25458,  57.25675,
       57.68244,  59.67495,  59.42791,  59.44048,  59.87237,  61.81162,  61.60417,
       61.63524,  62.06323,  63.39596,  63.19328,  63.14214,  63.49329,  65.63239,
       65.46829,  65.48508,  65.65813,  69.06712,  68.92904,  68.94045,  69.18806,
       73.69241,  73.47518,  73.42786,  73.82185,  69.54005,  69.59465,  69.85418,
       70.30283,  73.80306,  73.69583,  73.69901,  74.12954)

s <-ts(s, start = c(1999, 1), frequency = 4)
```

There is an intended jump in the values of s from t=21 onwards. Therefore, I create a Dummy:

```
t <- rep_len(1,68)
t[1:20] <- 0
t <-ts(t, start = c(1999, 1), frequency = 4)
```

A X13-ARIMA model to seasonally adjust the data including the dummy

```
s_a <- final(seas(s, outlier = NULL, xreg = t))
```

gives me the error:

```
Error: X-13 run failed

Errors:
- forecasts end date, 2018.4, must end on or before user-defined
  regression variables end date, 2015.4.
```

But actually, I am not interested in a forecast but the adjusted time series whithout a jump. So can I turn the forecast off or do I have to specify the seas() function differently?

Comment: In R indexes start at 1, not 0, so t[0:20] <- 0 will be treated as t[1:20] <- 0.  That is, it will drop the 0.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck, I changed the indexing.